# Measure which Java code is taking long to compile

Tags: java, performance, profiling, javacompiler

There is a large Java project that takes long to compile, both through Maven and through IntelliJ IDEA.

I want to try to improve that, but you know what they say about optimization without measurement, so here we are.

CPU use is at times 100% on all cores, but sometimes drops for 10+ seconds. RAM and disk are used but don't seem at capacity (judging from windows task manager).

I'd be interested in measuring anything that helps. Mostly which source files, which constructs, or which compilation steps.

(Details about project: millions of lines of code, dozens of maven projects, language level 8 but recent jdk)

Comment: Put the source files, build dependencies and `m2` folder on a ram drive. There aren't any tools with which I'm familiar that help with profiling compilation time, but you can use tools like jrebel to perform incremental builds.

Comment: Haven used it myself, but Intuit's [Maven Build Scanner](https://github.com/intuit/maven-build-scanner) looks promising.